# Excel: Using COUNTIF but not including blanks with other formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

Firstly, apologies if this is covered somewhere deep within the site, I have looked through a lot of other posts and none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm creating a workbook for a local league I'm involved in and this is the only sticking point I'm coming up against.

In cell J55, I have the formula:

`=IF(C11=H55, COUNTIF(D11, "="&E11),0)+IF(C19=H55, COUNTIF(D19, "="&E19),0)`

(I've simplified this to only look at rows 11 & 19 for the purposes of this question)

So what I'm essentially saying is if the team name is equal to the corresponding name in the table, count if the scores for both teams are equal. Basically I'm trying to get the number of games that end in a draw.

So at it's core, my formula is looking for whether 2 cells are equal. This is fine, other than it is counting even if the score cells are blank.

So if you refer to the below image, in J55, I'm getting the returned value of "2". However for the values I've populated in the results (just the scores in the first game) it should be returning a value of "1".

If anybody can help in any way it would be a great help.

[Screenshot of excel 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjtqF.png)
[Screenshot of excel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asY3C.png)

Comment: Why? First COUNTIF compares 10=10, giving 1. Second COUNTIF compares ""="", giving 1 too. The sum is 2 - everything is correct. *my formula is looking for whether 2 cells are equal*, but it do not check the cell contains a number.

Comment: Hi Akina. Yeah I agree it's correct. What I'm looking for is how to make the formula not count the cells if they're blank.

Thanks!

Comment: Add additional check into your formula. Something like `IF(AND(C11=H55, ISNUMBER(D11)), COUNTIF(D11, "="&E11),0) ...`

Comment: @liamtharris was this the same question you asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626464/using-countif-but-not-including-blanks-with-other-formula/52627311#52627311)?

Comment: @ForwardEd It was yeah. I'm new to the community and after that comment about it not being programming I thought it would be better suited here! Looks like there was a number of methods. The SUMPRODUCT was the winner though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered by Akina in the comments:

An extra check was all I needed to ensure the value was a number (ISNUMBER(XX)

```
IF(AND(C11=H55, ISNUMBER(D11)), COUNTIF(D11, "="&E11),0) ...
```